# Can I use .setVisibility(View.GONE) or should I just remove the View itself?

Tags: android, button, visibility

I have a layout and some dynamicly added buttons on it. Some times these buttons should just disapear, so i decided to use:

```
myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE)
```

is it a good way if I could have many buttons, for example 20-30 pieces?
or is it a better way to completly .remove the buttons from its layout then add again if needed, or i should just use the Visibility modifiler ?
Which better, cons and pros..!?

Comment: snapshot of ur UI would help us understand  which one's better for u

Answer (score 1):

If you really have 20-30 buttons for which visibility changes, I guess u should take the minimum number(I guess below 10) of buttons and change their properties instead of creating them or changing their visibility each time.

Comment: I makin a game so you really just cant predict whats going on in the layouts, so think about it:
My layout is a backpack, all the buttons are icons for "items" in the backpack, each has onClickListener with various abilities etc, 
I cannot determine what will the players hold and what they use, they may have only 2-3 pieces at their backpack or being greedy and use all the spaces. (30)

Answer (score 1):

20-30 buttons sounds like quite a lot. There's nothing wrong in using the visibility parameter generally, but if you're thinking about having this many views, you should probably consider just having a couple and reusing them for different things.

Comment: Visibility changing happens often, but not fast, and not much in the same time, so only one button changing, then some interactions, then the other, etc so if its ok to use the Visi modifiler, i mean if its aint gone do memory leak or something like that, i will keep in that way.
What do you think ?

Comment: You can. However, I think it's more of a hassle to manage the visibility of 30 views rather than just reusing a couple. Also, the more views you have in your layout, the longer it takes to inflate.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best and common way is to use .setVisibility(View.GONE)
Maybe the best way for you is to set ALL as gone by default (define it in the XML layout) and enable on demand.

For example I think that ListView is very smart and prefer that you mark a view as GONE than removing it.

And I think that Android in general is also smart too so it will understand that you wont need a view setted as gone :)

UPDATE:

maybe the best way for you is to add those buttons from code so you will create many buttons as you need :)

Comment: I creat the buttons from code, but as long as i dont need them, they are disappear by Visibility change, if its good i keep in that way, and if i need them again a use .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)

Answer (score 1):

If you need to remove them *and then show them again*, it could be better to just set visibility to gone and then change back to visible again, to avoid recreating a lot of buttons over and over again.
If you on the other hand *don't need them visible* again, simply remove them.

Comment: Okay, i need them again so Visi changing will be ok i think thank you!

Comment: I read you comment that it was to be the backpack in a game, if that is the case I would recommend you to keep all 30 buttons gone, and when you need to add an item in the backpack you modify a button and set it to visible (not creating a new one). When the user then uses the item you set the button back to gone.

Comment: However, I should think that you would be best of using a gridview, a listview or another view using an adapter. then you wouldn't have to worry about creating/hiding/removing buttons, as the view would handle that automatically for you.

Comment: What do you mean of "the view would handle that automatically for you"?
My buttons are on a simple LinearLayout, why gridview would be better?

Comment: The ListView would probably be the best in your case, it can take data from an ArrayList or an Array (or other data structures) and display as a list (that is, a scrollable linearlayout, kindof). If you add or remove an item to the array, the layout updates automatically. That is, you could have an array of items the user has in his backpack, and when he uses an item you remove it from the array. This causes the listview to remove the view corresponding to that item. If you add a new item to the array a new item is added in the list.

Comment: Very good, the problem is that i already coded this functionality by my self. Ah Its ok.